# CheckedListBoxControl Devexpress C# ---- Saving all items in MysQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, devexpress, checkedlistbox

Ok This is a new edit of this question, as you will see in my code below I make it so that I iterate through each item and then it is supposed to get the checked and unchecked value of each item and then save them in my MySql database, but well, the moment I save it does save but all items are saved in **boolean true**, not the boolean I'm assigning which is supposed to be **Boolean value**.
Meaning that if an item is checked the boolean should be true while an item isn't checked the boolean should be false, and that is supposed to be saved, but... well it saves **everything** in true.
How can I solve this problem I'm having?

```
private void SbtnGuarda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String id = txtId.Text.Trim();               
            for (int i = 0; i < CLBCpermits.ItemCount; i++)
            {
                object Row = CLBCpermits.GetItem(i);
                DataRowView rew = Row as DataRowView;
                Boolean value = Convert.ToBoolean(CLBCpermits.GetItemCheckState((int)rew["SecOptionId"] - 1));
                int opti = (int)rew["SecOptionId"];                   
                string qry = string.Format("INSERT INTO TblSecProfile (Id, OptActive, SecOptionId) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}');", id, value, opti);
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Global.ConnectionStringMySql))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(qry, conn))
                    {
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }      
            }

            XtraMessageBox.Show("Permits assigned to profile", "Process Finished", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            SbtnGuarda.Enabled = false;
            SbtnActualiza.Enabled = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error while giving permits", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks for bearing my like 4th time editing this post.

Comment: That must mean that `value` is always true.   Is `OptActive` a `BIT` in the database?

Comment: Yes, it is a `BIT` in database, but how can value always be true? If I'm saying that it must get the value of the item if is checked or not, thanks to the `GetItemCheckState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use query parameters.  Your current code is dangerous.  Look up "SQL Injection" if you aren't sure why I say that.

Now, using parameters, you'd have this:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO TblSecProfile (Id, OptActive, SecOptionId) VALUES (@id, @optActive, @secOptionId)";
```

And later...

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = id;
comm.Parameters.Add("@optActive", MySqlDbType.Bit).Value = value;
comm.Parameters.Add("@secOptionId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = opti;
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My guess is that because you are supplying a `String` value to the `BIT` typed column in the query, conversion is taking over and converting everything to `TRUE`.

Comment: I don't think there will be a problem with the injection, because I'm doing this while using a checkedlistboxcontrol and a pre-set id, although I will change the format if necessary, going to try out your solution now.

Comment: Ok Just triend and yes because I was sending a `String` value to the `Bit` type column I was having that everything was saved as true, Thank you a lot.

Comment: Also, using parameters gets you in the habit of writing better code, and forces you to properly respect data types.  Just a good all-around practice to get into.